# How would I get the UTC offset currently within the midnight hour?

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

I'd like to determine at any given moment which UTC offset is between the hour of `00:00` to `00:59`.

Is there a concise way to get this without resorting to just manually iterating over offsets?  Perhaps via a conversion from UTC's current time?

Comment: How is that the case here?  I have a problem that I'm looking to solve *and* I don't have an existing algorithm.  Seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: The point is that you have to give it a shot, otherwise we don't know what you're having problems with. If someone implements something here, that's just solving your problem. If you show what you have tried, the problem is more likely to be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone`<sup>1</sup> you can create a useful function:

```
/*
    Return UTC Offsets/Timezones in which is 00AM at passed time string
    
    @param    string    original time string (default: current time)
    @param    string    original timezone string (default: UTC)
    @param    bool      return as Timezones instead as UTC Offests (default: False)
    
    @retval   array     array of UTC Offsets or Timezones
*/
function getMidNight( $timeString=Null, $timeZone=Null, $returnTimeZone=False )
{
    $utc = new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' );
    $baseTimeZone = ( $timeZone ) ? new DateTimeZone( $timeZone ) : $utc;
    $date = new DateTime( $timeString, $baseTimeZone );

    $retval = array();
    foreach( DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $tz )
    {
        $currentTimeZone = new DateTimeZone( $tz );
        if( ! $date->setTimezone( $currentTimeZone )->format('G') )
        {
            if( $returnTimeZone ) $retval[] = $tz;
            else                  $retval[] = $date->getOffset();
        }
    }
    return array_unique( $retval );
}
```

The `G` format is 24 hours without leading zero, so at `00` is `False`.
[`->listIdentifiers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) returns a list of all defined timezone identifiers.

Then, calling it in this way<sup>2</sup>:

```
print_r( getMidNight() );
```

You will obtain<sup>3</sup>:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 46800
    [1] => -39600
)
```

And, calling it in this way<sup>2</sup>:

```
print_r( getMidNight( Null, Null, True ) );
```

You will obtain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Antarctica/McMurdo
    [1] => Pacific/Auckland
    [2] => Pacific/Enderbury
    [3] => Pacific/Fakaofo
    [4] => Pacific/Midway
    [5] => Pacific/Niue
    [6] => Pacific/Pago_Pago
    [7] => Pacific/Tongatapu
)
```

---

#### Notes:

1. php TimeZone has some bugs (reported in TimeDiff, but I alert you) when original DateTime is not in UTC format. So, check the function behavior before use it in production.
2. Tested at 13:43 UTC/GMT.
3. You ask for “the UTC offset”, but this definition is not precise: can be more than one TimeZones with same hour: so, the function return an array.